# Why doesn't it cache?

Tags: php, html, css, caching, http-headers

Okay, i've got a website (`https://illution.dk`) and almost all of my included/linked files are sending out an "304 Not Modified" header. 
Except for: 
`https://illution.dk/include/style.php`
which is always returning an "200 OK". My headers for style.php are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK => 
Date => Fri, 11 Nov 2011 15:44:39 GMT
Server => Apache/2.2.6 mod_auth_kerb/5.3 PHP/5.2.17 mod_fcgid/2.3.5
X-Powered-By => PHP/5.2.17
Expires => Sat, 12 Nov 2011 16:44:39 CET
Cache-Control => max-age=290304000, public
Pragma => 
Set-Cookie => PHPSESSID=dkh4jdqko9t6ihp760sn4v28a2; path=/; domain=.illution.dk
Last-Modified => Fri, 11 Nov 2011 15:52:18 GMT
Connection => close
Content-Type => text/css
```

What can the problem be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you also include headers for the files that _DO_ cache?

Comment: I know, but I can't do anything about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my test, the browsers sends the `If-Modified-Since` header

```
If-Modified-Since:Fri, 11 Nov 2011 15:57:48 GMT
```

But the page returned has the following modified date

```
Last-Modified:Fri, 11 Nov 2011 15:58:44 GMT
```

which is later that the `If-Modified-Since` date, which means the server side(PHP) thinks it always has a later version than the browser's cached version, causing it to send back the file every time.

Comment: Why is the browser sending an "Cache-Control:max-age=0"?